# urllib2: reading https url failure

Tags: python, https, openssl, urllib2

This code fails on my Ubuntu, but works well on other hosts.

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> urlopen("https://courtapps.utcourts.gov/XchangeWEB/login")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1408F119:SSL 
routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac>
```

What is the reason and how to fix this? I feel something is wrong with `OpenSSL`, have `v1.0.1` installed.

Comment: Fails for me also under Debian unstable. The problem seems to have nothing to do with Python, but with the underlying OpenSSL. Check [here](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Fw-1-0-0e-decryption-failed-or-bad-record-mac-td46197.html), for example (there are many other hits about this looking for your specific error).

Comment: This [Debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=678353) might be related.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Disabpling AES-NI doesn't help

Comment: Same problem appeared yesterday on Ubuntu, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom SSLv3 handler solves the problem:

```
import httplib, ssl, urllib2, socket
class HTTPSConnectionV3(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        httplib.HTTPSConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def connect(self):
        sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self.sock = sock
            self._tunnel()
        try:
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)
        except ssl.SSLError, e:
            print("Trying SSLv3.")
            self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

class HTTPSHandlerV3(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
    def https_open(self, req):
        return self.do_open(HTTPSConnectionV3, req)

# install opener
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(HTTPSHandlerV3()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r =   urllib2.urlopen("https://courtapps.utcourts.gov/XchangeWEB/login")
    print(r.read())
```