# GitLab SSL Read error, decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab

I want to add an existing Git repository to GitLab using this command : `git push -u origin --all` but I got the following error message :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/Name/MyProject.git/': SSL read: error:1
SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac, errno
0
```

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check if you can switch to ssh as a workaround:

```
git remote set-url git@gitlab.com:Name/MyProject.git
```

(you need to [generate a public/private key paris first, and register your public key to your GitLab profile](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html))

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21497591/6309) seems to reference a [Debian or OpenSSL bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=678353), so it depends on your OS and on your openssl version.

Comment: Make sure to upgrade to the latest Git version first, to see if the error persists